# Force an iframe's parent page to scroll to top automatically when the user navigates in the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, cross-domain

iFrame Loading Issue When iFrame loads to the Client page, we are seeing the page location jump around and, in the vast majority of cases, we see the page focus lower on the page.  This forces to have to scroll up to see the iframe application.

I have tried to fix this issue by using:

$('html,body', window.parent.document).animate({
                scrollTop: '0px'
}, 'fast');

iframe id="clientID" class="ad" src="https://www.our-application.com"

This not work because Client website and Our iframe based application window are on different domains, So we can’t have access on window.parent directly having cross-domain issue .

Kindly suggest how to fix this pls help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parent page to scroll to top when iframe's form validation fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911422/get-parent-page-to-scroll-to-top-when-iframes-form-validation-fails)

Answer (score 0):

**This answer will only work provided you can add a javascript event listener to the parent page.**

A 'message' event listener on the clients page you could use the `window.parent.postMessage()` function - see the Mozilla documentation below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

The idea is that within your iframe you use javascript to post a message to the parent window.

The parent window contains an event listener that then scrolls to top.

You should pay particular attention to the security concerns in the documentation above.

This answer provides a code example https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914498/7326037

> In the parent window, I had

```
function receiveMessage(e){

  console.log("Received Message: " + e);

  if (e.originalEvent.origin === 'http://www.site.client.com') {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop : 441
    }, "fast");
  }
}
$(window).bind("message", receiveMessage);
```

> and added this for the original js code for the iframe content:

```
window.parent.postMessage("Scroll", "http://www.site.client.com/");
```

> This results in the iframe posting a message that is captured by the
>   parent. Since this is the only message posted, I use it to trigger the
>   scroll event if and only if the domains match.

Comment: Hello Thanks for suggestion however We can't say to our client to add JavaScripts instead we have to provide only one element which is **iframe id="clientID" class="ad" src="https://www.our-application.com"** nothing else...Any solution without adding anything on Client domain?

Comment: As you mentioned your iframe is on a different domain and therefore the [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is going to prevent you from controlling the clients `window`. So I think it's probably going to be impossible for you to achieve this without them adding a javascript listener to their site.

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: If you cannot add any javascript to the clients webpage then you will not be able to control their page. Take a read through the Same Origin policy that I linked to above - the security implications of allowing a third party iframe to control the parent page are huge, which is why it is impossible for you to do so.

Comment: Perhaps you could contact the client and ask them to add some javascript to their page which would consume a postmessage event and scroll to the top.

Comment: Can you please help me to know what exactly JavaScript my Client needs to add and what i have to add so that i'll approach them accordingly  ? for example client.html will have our iframe and our iframe application HTML page name is myapplication.html so what script i need to add, please help me.

Comment: please let me know